# UISegmentedControll performs same action for every cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol, segmentedcontrol

I have a segmented controll with two cells defined programmatically. When I go into my app both cells perform the same action. The first should open a webpage in Safari, the second opens an image and covers the current view for 5 seconds. Any pointers?

In the .m file

```
@property UISegmentedControl *segment;

        - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        UISegmentedControl *segment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Publication", @"About", nil]];
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = segment;
        [segment addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];


        [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]
               forCellReuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    }


    - (void)segmentPressed:(id)sender {

        if (_segment.selectedSegmentIndex ==0) {

         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"******"]];

        }else if(_segment.selectedSegmentIndex ==1){

            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
            imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            [imageView setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"MACSLoad@2x.png"]];
            [self.view addSubview: imageView];
            sleep(5);
            imageView.hidden = YES;

        }


    }
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Answer (score 2):

You get that result because _segment is nil. You never assigned the segmented control you created to your property -- you assigned it to a local variable. So change this line,

```
UISegmentedControl *segment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Publication", @"About", nil]];
```

to,

```
self.segment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Publication", @"About", nil]];
```

Another way to do it, would be to get rid of the property all together, leave the code in viewDidLoad as it is, and change this,

```
- (void)segmentPressed:(id)sender {

        if (_segment.selectedSegmentIndex ==0) {
```

to this,

```
- (void)segmentPressed:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {

        if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex ==0) {
```

Unless you need to access the segmented control outside of its action method, there's no reason to create the property. It's better in any case to use the sender argument rather than a property (even if you have one) inside the action method.